# How do I get my previously adopted child to move into Bloodchill Manor?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I recently got the Bloodchill Manor Creation Club home for *Skyrim Special Edition* and I wanted to move my child there. I downloaded the Hearthfire Multiple Adoptions/Custom Home Support mod and it shows an "it's time to move" option whenever I talk to her, but there's no option to move her to Bloodchill Manor. I tried using the console commands for resetting her, but nothing worked.

I then tried the Unadopt mod and reset her AI to readopt her, and it had no option for her to move to Bloodchill Manor.

How do I get this to work? It seems that the game doesn't count Bloodchill as a home, even though it has 2 child beds in it.